# Not able to execute DataJpaTest

Tags: spring, spring-boot, testing, integration-testing

I have a `spring-data-jpa` repository called `TagRepository`. My `spring-boot` version is 2.1.2. I am using H2 dependency with runtime scope and I intend to use it for both the application and integration testing. I want to write a `DataJpaTest` for the TagRepository. I have written the following code:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@DataJpaTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes={TagRepository.class})
public class TagRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager testEntityManager;

    @Autowired
    private TagRepository tagRepository;

    @Test
    public void findByTagTest() {
        Tag tag = new Tag("java");
        testEntityManager.persistAndFlush(tag);

        Optional<Tag> optionalTag = tagRepository.findByTag(tag.getTag());
        if(!optionalTag.isPresent()) {
            fail("Tag not found hence test failed");
        }

        assertThat(optionalTag.get()).isEqualTo(tag);
    }
}
```

However, when I execute the test it says Application failed to start and I get following error:

```
Invalid bean definition with name 'tagRepository' defined in null: Cannot register bean definition [Root bean: class [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] for bean 'tagRepository': There is already [Generic bean: class [com.upday.task.repository.TagRepository]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] bound.

The bean 'tagRepository', defined in null, could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in null and overriding is disabled.

Action:

Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

The test class itself resides in a different package than jpa repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes={TagRepository.class})
```

from your test.

It is meant for passing a custom `@Configuration` not a regular bean.

**UPD**:
When data jpa test and the repository under test resides in a different packages spring runner needed a little hint to scan classes from another place. Pointing out the application class via

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes={SpringBootApplication.class})
```

will extend the component scan scope and allow test environment to pick up additional beans.

Comment: Then there is another error `TagRepositoryTest does not declare any static, non-private, non-final, nested classes annotated with @Configuration`

Comment: What kind of Configuration? What can I give in @Configuration to make the test work? I am new to this please help

Comment: @NavjotSingh I'm guessing that your test and your jpa repository resides in different packages. Put test into the same package as your repository.

Comment: But I don't want to put them in same packages. I want to make it work in different packages.

Comment: Well then try to specify your application configuration: @ContextConfiguration(classes={SprintBootApplication.class})

Comment: But cannot we just add @ComponentScan(basePackage = basepackagehere) and make it work?

Comment: For regular beans we can, in conjunction with `@EnableAutoConfiguration`. But spring data beans requires additional configuration.